# laravel 5.3 Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Routing\Router::middleware()

Tags: laravel-5

Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Routing\Router::middleware()

api.php

`Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});`

RouteServiceProvider.php

```
protected function mapApiRoutes()
{
Route::group([
    'middleware' => ['api', 'auth:api'],
    'namespace' => $this->namespace,
    'prefix' => 'api',
], function ($router) {
    require base_path('routes/api.php');
});
}
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. The problem is you can't call `Route::middleware('auth:api')` until version 5.4

In version 5.3 it must be called as `Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() { ... })`